# What does the ai core do when you give it to zed and what are the stats

Tags: borderlands-2

I finished the out of body experience mission I'm level 14 assassin and I'm debating to give the core to Marcus or zed could you help me out

Comment: This is an answer that could have easily been found by googling the quest name and game title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the core to Zed gives you a shield. Giving the core to marcus gives you a shotgun. Neither is particularly special besides being able to talk with the core's voice.